# Finding the static attributes of a class in Python

Tags: python, class-design

This is an unusual question, but I'd like to dynamically generate the `__slots__` attribute of the class based on whatever attributes I happened to have added to the class.

For example, if I have a class:

```
class A(object):
    one = 1
    two = 2

    __slots__ = ['one', 'two']
```

I'd like to do this dynamically rather than specifying the arguments by hand, how would I do this?

Comment: This smells of premature optimisation.  Can you discuss your use case a bit more?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense -- attributes are already defined dynamically, at run time.  Why mess with __slots__?  What are you planning to do with __slots__?

Comment: I've done a load of profiling and there's room for improving on the design I think. For 100,000 class instances, I want to remove the ability to dynamically defined attributes so the classes are more lightweight.

Comment: Also, the 'attributes' are a little more complicated than this example and contain objects that can be the same for every instance of the class (rather than instantiating one for each instance).

Comment: For high performance with 100,000 class instances, you might consider using Flyweight design pattern -- the attributes aren't in the class instance, they're simple tuples and the class is basically all static methods.

Comment: For multiple references to the same object the __slots__ thing is irrelevant.  Multiple references are simply multiple references to the same underlying object -- nothing needs to be done to makes this happen.

Comment: That's good advice, the __slots__ doesn't seem to make that much difference anyway, plus the flyweight design pattern could be really useful. Just posting a related question about this...

Comment: @Dan, the answer you have accepted does not work correctly, unless you wanted the attributes to be read-only, and to also include the other class metadata attributes (`__module__`, etc.).  Could you clarify your question, and/or accept my answer, which does do what you ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point you're trying to define **slots**, the class hasn't been built yet, so you cannot define it dynamically from within the A class.

To get the behaviour you want, use a metaclass to introspect the definition of A and add a slots attribute.

```
class MakeSlots(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['__slots__'] = attrs.keys()

        return super(MakeSlots, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class A(object):
    one = 1
    two = 2

    __metaclass__ = MakeSlots
```

Comment: Two problems with this answer: 1) it doesn't work; 2) even if it did work, it will also add methods, classes, *everything* that is defined in the class body into `__slots__`.  It doesn't work because the names, besides being in the newly created `__slots__`, are also in the class overriding the `__slots__` `memberdescriptor`s, and what we end up with is `AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'one'`

Comment: Argh -- above should be `AttributeError: 'A' object attribute 'one' is read-only`

Comment: While it's true that the class hasn't been built yet, you can still do it during class creation:  use `vars()`, and do it *last*.

Answer (score 1):

One very important thing to be aware of -- if those attributes stay in the class, the `__slots__` generation will be useless... okay,  maybe not *useless* -- it will make the class attributes read-only; probably not what you want.

The easy way is to say, "Okay, I'll initialize them to None, then let them disappear."  Excellent!  Here's one way to do that:

```
class B(object):
    three = None
    four = None

    temp = vars()                    # get the local namespace as a dict()
    __slots__ = temp.keys()          # put their names into __slots__
    __slots__.remove('temp')         # remove non-__slots__ names
    __slots__.remove('__module__')   # now remove the names from the local
    for name in __slots__:           # namespace so we don't get read-only
        del temp[name]               # class attributes
    del temp                         # and get rid of temp
```

If you want to keep those initial values it takes a bit more work... here's one possible solution:

```
class B(object):
    three = 3
    four = 4

    def __init__(self):
        for key, value in self.__init__.defaults.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    temp = vars()
    __slots__ = temp.keys()
    __slots__.remove('temp')
    __slots__.remove('__module__')
    __slots__.remove('__init__')
    __init__.defaults = dict()
    for name in __slots__:
        __init__.defaults[name] = temp[name]
        del temp[name]
    del temp
```

As you can see, it is possible to do this without a metaclass -- but who wants all that boilerplate?  A metaclass could definitely help us clean this up:

```
class MakeSlots(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_attrs = {}
        new_attrs['__slots__'] = slots = attrs.keys()
        slots.remove('__module__')
        slots.remove('__metaclass__')
        new_attrs['__weakref__'] = None
        new_attrs['__init__'] = init = new_init
        init.defaults = dict()
        for name in slots:
            init.defaults[name] = attrs[name]
        return super(MakeSlots, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, new_attrs)

def new_init(self):
    for key, value in self.__init__.defaults.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MakeSlots

    one = 1
    two = 2


class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = MakeSlots

    three = 3
    four = 4
```

Now all the tediousness is kept in the metaclass, and the actual class is easy to read and (hopefully!) understand.

If you need to have anything else in these classes besides attributes I strongly suggest you put whatever it is in a mixin class -- having them directly in the final class would complicate the metaclass even more.